# Thumbnail gallery image switching

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

```
function init(){

   th=document.getElementById('divId').getElementsByTagName('img');
for(c=0;c<th.length;c++) {
th[c].onclick=function() {
   swapImage(this.src);

   }
  }
 }

function swapImage(url){

   str=url.lastIndexOf(".");
   str1=url.substring(str-1);
   str2=url.substring(str);

   url=url.replace(str1,str2);

   document.getElementById('mainImage').src=url;

 }

   window.addEventListener?
   window.addEventListener('load',init,false):
   window.attachEvent('onload',init);
```

I'm mainly new to JS here, my main issue is specifically the JS section please help, I've been going at this for 4 days now. What the code should do is display a top image, and 5 thumbnails at the bottom. When clicked the thumbnails should display on to by switching with the current image.

Here is the HTML section of the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='gallery.css' type="text/css" rel ='stylesheet'/>
<title>Gallery</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <img id="mainImage" src="Images/alphamon.jpg"/>
    <br />
    <div align='center' id="divId" >
        <img class="imgStyle" src="Images/alphamon.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="Images/gallantmon.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="Images/omnimon.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="Images/omnimon_2.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="Images/royal_knights.jpg" />
    </div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='gallery.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is not working?what are the errors?did you debug ?

Comment: You appear to have a half-formed method (`window.addEventListener?`). What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you asking us what should go where the question mark is? Can you please also add your HTML, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem, also clearing stating what the *desired* functionality is. That way we can know how your current code doesn't perform in the way you want it to.

Comment: thank you for fast reply, i have a gallery where there's a big image on top, and below are 5 thumbnail images. when i try to click a thumbnail to display the image on top,the top div where the image is supposed to display goes blank. again brand new to js so im very sorry if the explanation vague.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is much easier.

```
function swapImage(url){
/* no need this code
   str=url.lastIndexOf(".");
   str1=url.substring(str-1);
   str2=url.substring(str);

   url=url.replace(str1,str2);
*/
   document.getElementById('mainImage').src=url;

 }
```

Comment: alex, awhile ago you helped me very much with this answer, i was wondering if you can help me with this one. the link is below:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660271/making-list-clickable-to-load-ajax-request-into-div

Comment: I added the answer. Again, it is good tradition to **accept** working answers.