# making list clickable to load ajax request into div

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How can I make a clickable list in jquery where each item in the list is it own link not using HTML just jquery/ajax/json

I need to make a clickable list in jquery.

what I need to do is to make it so that any user clicking on the list item runs an actual AJAX request. The data returned from that request must then be used to fill the box on the right side of the page.

I’m stuck on the on click function I create and i’m not sure what to do next and when I run the page the people.json file isnt appearing on the page

my javascript

```
'use strict';

$(function() {

$('#resultBox').click(function() {
  let url = $(this).data('url');
  makeAjaxRequest(url);
});


function makeAjaxRequest (url) {
 let request = $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'people.json'
      });

 request.done(function(data) {
        let list = data.body.list;
        let resultBox = $('#result-box');
        let unorderedList = $('<ul>');
        resultBox.append(unorderedList);

        for (let person of list) {
            let listItem = $('<li>');
            listItem.text(person.name);
            listItem.attr('data-url', person.links[0].href);
            unorderedList.append(listItem);
        }

    });

    request.fail(function(response) {
        console.log('ERROR:' + response.statusText);
    });


}
});
```

people.js

```
{
  "links":[ {
    "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people.json"
  }
  ,
  {
    "rel": "parent", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api.json"
  }
  ],
  "head": {
    "title": "People", "type":"listnav"
  }
  ,
  "body": {
    "list":[ {
      "name":"Adam",
      "links":[ {
        "rel": "self", "href":"http://www.philart.net/api/people/325.json"
      }
      ]
    }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <title>AJAX</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loaded-data"></div>
  <a href="#">
    <div id="result-box">
      <a></div>





</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#loaded-data {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 30px;

}
```

what the result should be is that by clicking the names on the list, i can make a ajax request and load the data of each url into the div.

Answer (score 0):

Build "people" list and add `click` handler to each `li`. Something like this.

```js
'use strict';
$(function() {
  $('#a-load').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let url = $(this).data('url');
    makeAjaxRequest(url);
  });

  function makeAjaxRequest(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        let list = data.body.list;
        let resultBox = $('#result-box');
        let unorderedList = $('<ul>');
        resultBox.append(unorderedList);
        list.forEach(function(el) {
          $('<li />').html(el.name)
            //.data('url', el.links[0].href) //no need
            .click(function() {// use it in closure
              loadDetails(el.links[0].href);
            })
            .appendTo(unorderedList);
        });
      })
      .fail(function(response) {
        conslole.log(response.status);
      });
  }

  function loadDetails(url) {
    //console.log(url);
    //make ajax request and fill loaded-data
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        let resultBox = $('#loaded-data').empty();
        data.body.art.forEach(function(el) {
          //console.log(el.title);
          $('<h2 />').html(el.title.display)
            .appendTo(resultBox);
          //process other things
        });
      })
      .fail(function(response) {
        conslole.log(response.status);
      });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#loaded-data {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loaded-data"></div>
<a id="a-load" href="#" data-url="http://www.philart.net/api/people.json">People</a>
<div id="result-box">
</div>
```